# Проблемы с кодировкой после использования циклов и массивов

Tags: php, массивы, кодировка, циклы

Добрый день, первый раз столкнулся с такой проблемой! На локальном денвере пытаюсь научиться писать на php, все бы ничего, только кодировка каким-то мистическим образом после пары проходов через циклы начала меняться на ромбики! Страница оформлена как положено, все меты, вся разметка, везде прописано utf-8, файлы тоже сохранены в этом формате, и база тоже пишет в utf-8. Причем пробовал на другом пк, тоже самое...

```html
<?php
@session_start();
$host="localhost";      /*Имя сервера*/
$user="root";         /*Имя пользователя*/
$password="";     /*Пароль пользователя*/
$db="wash";    /*Имя базы данных*/
mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) or die("MySQL сервер недоступен!".mysql_error());  /*Подключение к серверу*/
mysql_select_db($db) or die("Нет соединения с БД".mysql_error());         /*Подключение к базе данных на сервере*/
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
setlocale (LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF-8");
?>


<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html/php"; charset="utf8">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/select.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/search.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/search.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/tabl.css">
```

Comment: В вашем примере вы два раза вставили mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);
отпечатка?

Comment: действительно, только это ни на что не повлияло (

Comment: двойное подключение и не повлияет на кодировку) вы проверили мой ответ?

Comment: конечно, причем интересно что слова не полностью заменяются, я пробовал удалять из базы, новые записывать, разницы ноль  Array ( [0] => Сухой туман#3 [1] => 1�бразивная полировка#2 [2] => Жидкое стекло#3 [4] => Мойка кузова включая пороги и продувка#1 [�] => Array ( [price] => 0 [vol] => 0 ) [7] => Array ( [price] => 7 [vol] => 1 ) [3] => Array ( [price] => 3 [vol] => 1 ) )

Comment: В базе-то посмотрите, что действительно сохранено. И от `mysql_` функций давно пора отказаться. Это расширение устарело с версии 5.5, а в PHP 7 его уже нет.

Comment: в базе все ОК, пробовал даже редактировать, удалять, выскакивает в другой переменной такая же фигня

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте явно поставить кодировку при подключении к базе:

```
$con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) or die("Error".mysql_error()); 
mysql_set_charset($con,"utf8");
........
```

Comment: только ошибку получил Warning: mysqli_set_charset() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in Z:\home\localhost\www\Wash\adm\connect.php on line 8

Comment: да я по инерции записал подключение mysqli - a у вас mysql

Comment: теперь ещё раз проверьте

Comment: такая же фигня, писал вот так $con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) or die("MySQL сервер недоступен!".mysql_error());  /*Подключение к серверу*/
mysql_set_charset($con,"utf8");

Comment: т.е sql ошибка исчезла но кодировка не помогла?

Comment: нет, ошибка не исчезла, но у меня прописано mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");, разве это ни одно и тоже? я так же  iconv() пробовал, кодировку меняет, но тоже не читаемо

Comment: @Dimastik86, это разные вещи.

Answer (score 0):

ошибка пропадает, когда убираю цикл

> for ($i=0; $i < count($mv_today); $i++)

```html
for ($i=0; $i < count($mv_today); $i++) { 
  foreach ($mv_today[$i] as $key => $value) {
    if(!isset($tmp[$key]))
    {
      $tmp[$key] = $value;
    }
    else
    {
      $tmp[$key]['vol'] = $tmp[$key]['vol'] + $value['vol'];
      $tmp[$key]['price'] = $tmp[$key]['price'] + $value['price'];
    }
  }
}
```